# Suppressing summary information in `wc -l` output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wc

I use the command `wc -l` count number of lines in my text files (also i want to sort everything through a pipe), like this:

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | sort -rn
```

The output includes "total" line, which is the sum of lines of all files:

```
10 total
5 ./directory/1.txt
3 ./directory/2.txt
2 ./directory/3.txt
```

Is there any way to suppress this summary line? Or even better, to change the way the summary line is worded? For example, instead of "10", the word "lines" and instead of "total" the word "file".

Comment: The `man` page for `wc` doesn't mention any such functionality. You can whip up a script (or probably use pipes and `awk`) to change the appearance of the output.

Comment: Pipe it to `tail +2` to skip the first line.

Comment: @Barmar: That's unreliable. It only prints the `total` line if there's more than one file. And at least on my system, the `total` line is printed last -- as POSIX specifically requires. ipo: Do you really get the output you show, with the `10 total` line at the top?

Comment: Based on your comments, I think you're seeing `10 total` at the top because you're sorting the output. You need to mention that in the question. Show us the exact command you're running, and its exact output. And `$directory-path` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yet a `sed` solution!

#### 1. short and quick

As total are comming on last line, `$d` is the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command for deleting last line.

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | sed '$d'
```

#### 2. with header line addition:

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | sed '$d;1ilines total'
```

Unfortunely, there is no alignment.

#### 3. With alignment: formatting left column at 11 char width.

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt |
    sed -e '
        s/^ *\([0-9]\+\)/          \1/;
        s/^ *\([0-9 ]\{11\}\) /\1 /;
        /^ *[0-9]\+ total$/d;
        1i\      lines filename'
```

Will do the job

```
      lines file
          5 ./directory/1.txt
          3 ./directory/2.txt
          2 ./directory/3.txt
```

#### 4. But if really your `wc` version could put total on 1st line:

This one is for *fun*, because I don't belive there is a `wc` version that put total on 1st line, but...

This version drop *total* line everywhere and add header line at top of output.

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt |
    sed -e '
        s/^ *\([0-9]\+\)/          \1/;
        s/^ *\([0-9 ]\{11\}\) /\1 /;
        1{
            /^ *[0-9]\+ total$/ba;
            bb;
           :a;
            s/^.*$/      lines file/
        };
        bc;
       :b;
        1i\      lines file' -e '
       :c;
        /^ *[0-9]\+ total$/d
    '
```

This is more complicated because we won't drop 1st line, even if it's *total* line.

Comment: I'm reasonably sure he's seeing the `total` on the first line because he's sorting the output. He's mentioned this in comments, but needs to say so in the question. And there's no indication that he wants or needs the `"lines filename"` header that your solutions produce.

Comment: Seems too complicated for such a small operation.

Comment: @KeithThompson Asker said: *For example, instead of "10", the word "lines" and instead of "total" the word "file"* !

Comment: @codeforester It *seem* complicated because you won't try to understand. I'ts not as simple, but it's very quick and work as *standalone* solution

Comment: @codeforester Ok, there is a simplier [tag:sed] version: **2 characters**!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly tricky.

I'm basing this on the GNU coreutils version of the `wc` command. Note that the `total` line is normally printed last, not first (see my comment on the question).

`wc -l` prints one line for each input file, consisting of the number of lines in the file followed by the name of the file. (The file name is omitted if there are no file name arguments; in that case it counts lines in stdin.)

If and only if there's more than one file name argument, it prints a final line containing the total number of lines and the word `total`. The documentation indicates no way to inhibit that summary line.

Other than the fact that it's preceded by other output, that line is indistinguishable from output for a file whose name happens to be `total`.

So to reliably filter out the `total` line, you'd have to read all the output of `wc -l`, and remove the final line only if the total length of the output is greater than 1. (Even that can fail if you have files with newlines in their names, but you can probably ignore that possibility.)

A more reliable method is to invoke `wc -l` on each file individually, avoiding the `total` line:

```
for file in $directory-path/*.txt ; do wc -l "$file" ; done
```

And if you want to sort the output (something you mentioned in a comment but not in your question):

```
for file in $directory-path/*.txt ; do wc -l "$file" ; done | sort -rn
```

If you happen to know that there are no files named `total`, a quick-and-dirty method is:

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | grep -v ' total$'
```

If you want to run `wc -l` on all the files and then filter out the `total` line, here's a bash script that should do the job.  Adjust the `*.txt` as needed.

```
#!/bin/bash

wc -l *.txt > .wc.out
lines=$(wc -l < .wc.out)
if [[ lines -eq 1 ]] ; then
    cat .wc.out
else
    (( lines-- ))
    head -n $lines .wc.out
fi
rm .wc.out
```

Another option is this Perl one-liner:

```
wc -l *.txt | perl -e '@lines = <>; pop @lines if scalar @lines > 1; print @lines'
```

`@lines = <>` slurps all the input into an array of strings. `pop @lines` discards the last line if there are more than one, i.e., if the last line is the `total` line.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. But i have to use `wc -l` at the end, because i also have to sort them. Thats not possible, when I do `wc -l` on each file. The quick-and-dirty method is also not so good. Maybe i have a file named 'total'.

Comment: @ipo: Sure you can sort the output: `for file in $directory-path/*.txt ; do wc -l "$file" ; done | sort -rn`. (I'm assuming you're using a Bourne-derived shell like bash.)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Done. (I thought I had; not sure how I missed that.)

Comment: You miss: `/bin/ls -1 *.txt | xargs -n1 wc -l` and/or `find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} \;` ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri: I wouldn't say I "missed" those. I didn't intend to show all possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The program wc, always displays the total when they are two or more than two files ( fragment of wc.c):

```
if (argc > 2)
     report ("total", total_ccount, total_wcount, total_lcount);
   return 0;
```

also the easiest is to use wc with only one file and find present - one after the other - the file to wc:

```
find $dir -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Or as specified by liborm.

```
dir="."
find $dir -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} \; | sort -rn | sed 's/\.txt$//'
```

Comment: Thats nearly the solution! But i need to pipe this one as well to `| sort -rn | sed 's/\.txt$//' ` Where should i place this pipe? I tried `find $dicitonary-path/*.txt-exec wc -l {} \ | sort -rn | sed 's/\.txt$//';` ...but this is wrong.

Comment: I think you're missing a `-name` argument in your `find` command.

Comment: @ipo like that, but without the typos.. `find $PATH -name '*.txt' -exec wc -l {} \; | sort -rn | sed 's/\.txt$//'`

Comment: @liborm :Thank's, i have put your cmd inside my response. If it's a problem, i can remove it.

Comment: @Keith Thompson : You're right, thank's for your help.

Comment: @ipo: Why would you want to strip the `.txt` portion of the file names (`sed 's/\.txt$//'`)? You really need to update your question and state the problem more precisely. Read this: [mcve]

Comment: It's 2 or more files, not more than 2 files. `argc` is the number of arguments including `argv[0]`, which is the program name (`"wc"`).

Answer (score 1):

This is a job tailor-made for head:

```
wc -l | head --lines=-1
```

This way, you can still run in one process.

Comment: There are a lot of complicated solutions from people having fun with the problem, but `head -n -1` *before* sorting seems best. Surprising that `wc` does not have a quiet or script use mode.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use another wc ?

The POSIX `wc`(`man -s1p wc`) shows
*If more than one input file operand is specified, an additional line shall be written, of the same format  as the other lines, except that the word total (in the POSIX locale) shall be written instead of a pathname and the total of each column shall be written as appropriate. Such an additional  line, if any, is written at the end of the output.*

You said the Total line was the first line, the manual states its the last and other wc's don't show it at all. Removing the first or last line is dangerous, so I would `grep -v` the line with the total (in the POSIX locale...), or just grep the slash that's part of all other lines:

```
wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | grep "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most optimized way since you can use combinations of `cat`, `echo`, `coreutils`, `awk`, `sed`, `tac`, etc., but this will get you want you want:

```
wc -l ./*.txt | awk 'BEGIN{print "Line\tFile"}1' | sed '$d'
```

`wc -l ./*.txt` will extract the line count. `awk 'BEGIN{print "Line\tFile"}1'` will add the header titles. The `1` corresponds to the first line of the stdin. `sed '$d'` will print all lines except the last one.

**Example Result**

```
Line    File
      6 ./test1.txt
      1 ./test2.txt
```

Comment: All i get is something like this 'Line File' above '10 total'. So like your example, but with the total-information again.

Comment: @ipo: what kind of system are you running? I'm using zsh on a OSX system. My total line count appears at the end. Try using this: `wc -l ./*.txt | awk 'BEGIN{print "Line\tFile"}1' | sed '2d'`. The only difference is that the `sed` should delete the 2nd line, not the last line now.

Answer (score 0):

### The simplicity of using just `grep -c`

I rarely use `wc -l` in my scripts because of these issues.  I use `grep -c` instead. Though it is not as efficient as `wc -l`, we don't need to worry about other issues like the summary line, white space, or forking extra processes.

For example:

```
/var/log# grep -c '^' *
alternatives.log:0
alternatives.log.1:3
apache2:0
apport.log:160
apport.log.1:196
apt:0
auth.log:8741
auth.log.1:21534
boot.log:94
btmp:0
btmp.1:0
<snip>
```

Very straight forward for a single file:

```
line_count=$(grep -c '^' my_file.txt)
```

### Performance comparison: `grep -c` vs `wc -l`

```
/tmp# ls -l *txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 721009809 Dec 29 22:09 x.txt
-rw-r----- 1 root root 809338646 Dec 29 22:10 xyz.txt

/tmp# time grep -c '^' *txt

x.txt:7558434
xyz.txt:8484396

real    0m12.742s
user    0m1.960s
sys 0m3.480s

/tmp/# time wc -l *txt
   7558434 x.txt
   8484396 xyz.txt
  16042830 total

real    0m9.790s
user    0m0.776s
sys 0m2.576s
```

Comment: But `grep -c .` counts non-empty lines. You'll probably want `grep -c ''` as an approximation of `wc -l` (the two differ by one if the last “line” doesn't end with a newline).

Comment: Wonderful observation, @gniourf_gniourf.  I changed the command to `grep -c '^'`.

Comment: `grep -c '^'` also differs by one from `wc -l` if the last line doesn't end with a newline. In fact `grep` (at least the GNU version) always silently appends a newline if the last line doesn't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it (and many other problems that appear to need a `for` loop)  quite succinctly using **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
parallel wc -l ::: tmp/*txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
   3 tmp/lines.txt
   5 tmp/unfiltered.txt
  42 tmp/file.txt
   6 tmp/used.txt
```

Comment: `parallel -j1` if your files are really big, otherwise you'll clog your disk with parallel requests for data..

Comment: Possibly, though many folk run very fast SSDs nowadays and there was no indication that OP is using excessively large files and it could actually be an advantage to use **GNU Parallel** there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Mark Setchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41387951/838871) you can also use `xargs` with an explicit separator:

```sh
ls | xargs -I% wc -l %
```

Then `xargs` explicitly doesn't send all the inputs to `wc`, but one operand line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest answer:

```
ls | xargs -l wc
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using sed with the pattern removal option as below which would only remove the total line if it is present (but also any files with total in them).

wc -l $directory-path/*.txt | sort -rn | sed '/total/d'

Answer (score 0):

While most of the answers center around removing the unneeded line, or using a version of `wc` that allows suppressing it, there's something to be said in favor of never producing it in the first place.

So you want to count lines in `$directory-path/*.txt` files, however feeding several files to `wc` will produce the total — which you don't want.

I would change your pipeline to find the files and feeding them to `wc` one by one, in this manner:

```
find $directory-path -name "*.txt" | xargs -L 1 wc -l | sort -rn
```

In this case, `find` is tasked with locating files, while `xargs -L 1` is tasked with feeding them to `wc` one by one.